# Unrecognized Barcode

Tags: ios, decode, barcode-scanner, pdf417

[image]I need to parse the USDL (U.S driving Licence) barcodes which is in PDF417 format. I almost got the parsing, but when parse a barcode from ohio state. It shows unrecognized barcode information.

> o/p-OHLOVELAND^NEAL$RAYMOND$E$^11947 FOXGATE
>   WAYGDGACDBJBBBBJBFGXBGAGBJHBAGCBBAEFBEABIJA  3 1
>   BFBACBA1.:70

I don't get any idea to parse this output format.
I tried different Barcode scanner available in online,but no one works fine.

Is there any idea to parse this result?

Comment: What's your question here? Is your issue that you are getting the wrong data from scanning the barcode or is the problem that you don't know how to parse the data you do get?

Comment: i read that all US Licences are encoded in a common way.i know to parse that format. its an exception for that. i don't know to parse such data